# Material Datepicker is not working in Angular4

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Material Datepicker is not working in angular4 project. I did it everything as shown in angular official documantation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) but still it gives an error.
This is my module

```
import { MdTabsModule, MdProgressSpinnerModule, MdInputModule, MdDatepickerModule, MdNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';
```

This is imports

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MdTabsModule,
MdProgressSpinnerModule,
MdInputModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
AmChartsModule,
MdDatepickerModule,
MdNativeDateModule,
```

And This is HTML

```
<md-form-field>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <md-datepicker-toggle mdSuffix [for]="picker"></md-datepicker-toggle>
  <md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
</md-form-field>
```

Error ScreenShot

[image]

Angular Version

[image]

Comment: which version of material 2 you are using ?

Comment: added in question now

Comment: Update to material 2.0.0-beta.10 , `<md-datepicker-toggle>` has been introduced in that version.

Comment: how to upgrade it?

Comment: what version of material, not angular

Comment: Change version of angular material in your `package.json`, then run `npm install`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<md-datepicker-toggle>` has been introduced in material2 version `2.0.0-beta.10`.

> **mdDatepickerToggle** is now an element **< md-datepicker-toggle >** with a for
>   property that points to the MdDatepicker instance

Here is a link to complete [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta10-d%C3%A9coupage-panjandrum-2017-08-29). Using `<md-datepicker-toggle>` will throw an error if you have version [2.0.0-beta.8](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta8-plasma-abacus-2017-07-06) or lower installed. To update to the new version, do the following:

- In your `package.json`, change `"@angular/material"` and `"@angular/cdk"` version to `"2.0.0-beta.10"`
- In your terminal window, navigate to the folder in your project where `package.json` is located.
- Run the command `npm install`

Here is a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-76wdyx?file=app/app.module.ts) using version 2.0.0-beta.10.